# Not able to update a list with set state in textfield onchanged method

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, flutter-listview

I want to update a list of type `SongModel` when I enter a value in the `TextField`. However, the list is not updating when `onChanged` is called.

```dart
List<SongModel> songs = item.data!;
              List<SongModel> filterSongs = [];
              //showing the songs
              return Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      controller: searchController,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        //pass value for the search
                        getSearch(filterSongs,songs);
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(............
```

`getSearch()` :

```
getSearch(List<SongModel> filterSongs,List<SongModel> songs)
{
  var text = searchController.text;
  if (text.isEmpty) {
    setState(() {
      filterSongs = songs;
    });
  }
  print(songs.where((SongModel item) => item.title.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())).toList());
  print(text);
  setState(() {
    // search = text;
    filterSongs = songs.where((SongModel item) => item.title.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())).toList();
  });
  print(filterSongs.length);
}
```

Here the list is not updating with set state method.

Comment: Can you show the full file maybe? It's hard to judge because you only showed pieces. But it looks like you declare a local `filterSongs` inside your build method. It should be outside it probably

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `getSearch` method, you are setting the value of the parameter passed to `getSearch`, not the value of the list outside of that method. You should move the `filterSongs` list declaration outside of your `build` method anyways so that it isn't redeclared every time the screen is rebuilt.

```dart
class MyScreenClassState extends State<MyScreenClass>{
    //Create State method here
    

    List<SongModel> filterSongs = [];

    //Build method here

}
```

```dart
getSearch(List<SongModel> songs)
{
  var text = searchController.text;
  if (text.isEmpty) {
    setState(() {
      filterSongs = songs;
    });
  }
  print(songs.where((SongModel item) => item.title.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())).toList());
  print(text);
  setState(() {
    // search = text;
    filterSongs = songs.where((SongModel item) => item.title.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())).toList();
  });
  print(filterSongs.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If **onChanged** method doesn't work for your implementation, you can try this structure I think I will work for you.

```
 final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

 
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(_onControllerChange);
    
  }

@override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

 void _onControllerChange() async {

.....


}
```